# XSLT to create nested file and copy top element id to children

Tags: xml, xslt

Following on from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074043/created-nested-xml-from-flat-xml) I've realised that I need to have a copy of the top level element id and title in each of the child records as well as having them organised into a nested structure. So my ideal end result will look like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table name="ecatalogue">
   <collection>
      <tuple>
         <atom name="irn">2470</atom>
         <atom name="EADUnitID"/>
         <atom name="EADUnitTitle">Parent title</atom>
         <atom name="EADLevelAttribute"/>
         <tuple name="children">
            <tuple>
               <atom name="irn">5416</atom>
               <atom name="EADUnitID"/>
               <atom name="EADUnitTitle"/>
               <atom name="Parent_irn">2470</atom>
               <atom name="Parent_title">Parent title</atom>
            </tuple>
            <tuple>
               <atom name="irn">7</atom>
               <atom name="EADUnitID"/>
               <atom name="EADUnitTitle"/>
               <atom name="Parent_irn">2470</atom>
               <atom name="Parent_title">Parent title</atom>
               <tuple name="children">
                  <tuple>
                     <atom name="irn">8</atom>
                     <atom name="ObjectType"/>
                     <atom name="EADLevelAttribute"/>
                     <atom name="EADUnitID"/>
                     <atom name="EADUnitTitle"/>
                     <atom name="Parent_irn">2470</atom>
                     <atom name="Parent_title">Parent title</atom>
                  </tuple>
               </tuple>
            </tuple>
         </tuple>
      </tuple>
   </collection>
</table>
```

I've had a go at trying to do this myself and I couldn't find a way to edit the existing XSLT to enable me to do this. In the end I tried to write another XSLT which would go over the result from the first one and copy the parent irn and title to its children. Applying this to a small dataset seemed to work OK, however on a larger dataset it just hangs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="collection/record">    
    <record>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=" @* | node()"/>
        <tuple name="top_record">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="atom[@name='irn']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="atom[@name='EADUnitTitle']"/>
        </tuple>
    </record>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tuple[@name='children']/record">    
    <record>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=" @* | node()"/>
        <tuple name="top_record">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::collection/record/atom[@name='irn']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::collection/record/atom[@name='EADUnitTitle']"/>
        </tuple>
    </record>    
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I'd ideally like is one XSLT which creates a nested format and includes the parent irn and title in its children.

**EDIT**

Apologies: the original xml input looks like:

```
<table name="ecatalogue">
  <tuple>
    <atom name="irn">2470</atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitID"></atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitTitle"></atom>
    <atom name="EADLevelAttribute"></atom>
    <tuple name="AssParentObjectRef">
    </tuple>
  </tuple>

  <tuple>
    <atom name="irn">5416</atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitID"></atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitTitle"></atom>
    <tuple name="AssParentObjectRef">
      <atom name="irn">2470</atom>
      <atom name="EADUnitTitle"></atom>
    </tuple>
  </tuple>

  <tuple>
    <atom name="irn">7</atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitID"></atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitTitle"></atom>
    <tuple name="AssParentObjectRef">
      <atom name="irn">2470</atom>
      <atom name="EADUnitTitle"></atom>
    </tuple>
  </tuple>

  <tuple>
    <atom name="irn">8</atom>
    <atom name="ObjectType"></atom>
    <atom name="EADLevelAttribute"></atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitID"></atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitTitle"></atom>
    <tuple name="AssParentObjectRef">
      <atom name="EADUnitTitle"></atom>
      <atom name="irn">7</atom>
    </tuple>
  </tuple>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add an example of the XML input to your question here.

Comment: Apologies - I've amended the question to include the original xml I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to have a copy of the top level element id and title in each of
>   the child records

Pass them down as parameters:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="tuple" use="tuple[@name='AssParentObjectRef']/atom[@name='irn']" />

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <table name="ecatalogue">
        <collection>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tuple[not(tuple[@name='AssParentObjectRef']/atom[@name='irn'])]"/>
        </collection>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tuple">
    <xsl:param name="top-irn" select="atom[@name='irn']"/>
    <xsl:param name="top-title" select="atom[@name='EADUnitTitle']"/>
    <tuple>
        <xsl:copy-of select="atom"/>
        <atom name="Parent_irn">
            <xsl:value-of select="$top-irn"/>
        </atom>
        <atom name="Parent_title">
            <xsl:value-of select="$top-title"/>
        </atom>
        <xsl:if test="key('child', atom[@name='irn'])">
            <tuple name="children">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', atom[@name='irn'])">
                    <xsl:with-param name="top-irn" select="$top-irn"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="top-title" select="$top-title"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
             </tuple>
        </xsl:if>
    </tuple>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Applying this to my xml file using xsltproc I get the following errors:

`xsltproc -o output1.xml emu-nest-top.xsl import.xml
runtime error: file emu-nest-top.xsl line 18 element param
Unexpected XSLT element 'param'.
runtime error: file emu-nest-top.xsl line 19 element param
Unexpected XSLT element 'param'.
runtime error: file emu-nest-top.xsl line 22 element value-of
Variable 'top-irn' has not been declared.
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
runtime error: file emu-nest-top.xsl line 22 element value-of
XPath evaluation returned no result.`

Comment: OK... those errors appear to be because of the location of <xsl:param> statements. Moving them above the opening <tuple> tag allows xsltproc to transform the xml. A cursory examination of the output xml and everything seems to be good... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, that was careless of me - fixed now.